# Delete Smartgit config directory not removing everything

Tags: git, github, smartgit

I'm on OSX and using SmartGit (maybe not any more because it drives me crazy). I wanted to add another github account. I could not push because somehow SmartGit was using the old one. I deleted the

```
~/Library/Preferences/SmartGit
```

folder and restarted. SmartGit asked for new license agreement and everything. When it opened my repositories where still there and it still tried to use the old credentials. Is there some magic folder not documented by syntevo?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I haven't used SmartGit, but my assumption is that if deleting the config folder it doesn't remove your credentials, then those credentials are managed by Git instead. Are you using SSH or HTTPS? Can you post the contents of `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: Try to (temporarily disabled) `credential.helper` in your `~/.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `@mstrap` and `@Scott Weldon` if found out that the `credential.helper` was indeed causing this. OSX uses the `osxkeychain`to store credentials. I deleted the old username and password to get rid of this behavior. That fixed it for me.

Still not sure how to manage two github accounts. 
And I still don't know why SmartGit knew my repository locations after deleting the configs.